# Android Webdriver - How can I use a different port on localhost for WebDriver Hub?

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver

I am just getting started with Android Webdriver.

I have successfully setup my first tests and I am using an HTC One V to run them, after following all the steps mentioned here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver

However, on my local host, I am also running a Jenkins instance which is normally started on 8080, and I would like to keep Jenkins running on this port and change the port of the Android Webdriver server.

Is it possible to have the webdriver hub running on the local host on a port other than 8080?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use another port on the PC.

Try changing the value in the adb forward command to something like: `adb forward tcp:8090 tcp:8080` which would mean the port on your PC to use would be 8090 in your scripts, etc. [Remember to start WebDriver running on the Android device first.]

You can easily test this connects OK by using a web browser to connect to `http://localhost:8090/wd/hub/status/` the response will appear as a web page with something like `{status:0}`

Here are the details from adb:

```
adb forward <local> <remote> - forward socket connections
                               forward specs are one of: 
                               tcp:<port>
                               localabstract:<unix domain socket name>
                               localreserved:<unix domain socket name>
                               localfilesystem:<unix domain socket name>
                               dev:<character device name>
                               jdwp:<process pid> (remote only)
```